# registerCallback method for a custom button - facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get user profile data;
I'm following this tutorial :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837

The above tutorial uses `registerCallback` method like this:

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
.
.
.
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
});
```

now, How can I implement this method for a custom Button ?

---

below link use Facebook class, but for me this class undefined!

```
// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook;
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 6):

You can use [LoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/) to accomplish it without use the LoginButton.

First, you have to create the `CallbackManager` as usual:

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Next, you have to register the callback created with `LoginManager` instance:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
    }
});
```

And finally, you have to invoke the Facebook login with some permissions, for example:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
```

Don't forget override the `onActivityResult` method and call `onActivityResult` method from the `CallbackManager`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first step was to include the built in facebook button in my xml file but set its visibility to "gone" so it cannot be seen by the user.

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />
```

In my main activity, I then defined the hidden facebook button and the button I wanted to use

```
fbLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.authButton); //built in facebook button
customButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customButton); //my custom button
```

Then in an onClickListener for the custom button, I used the ".performClick" method on the facebook button

```
customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fbLoginButton.performClick();
    }
});
```

This works like a charm for me. Hopefully this can help somebody.

[@Rich Luick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509848/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-login-by-custom-button) tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I give step by step code for make facebook button custom.    [check code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928)

you just have to make a frame layout.